# Dismissing errors in Netlogo behavior space

Tags: netlogo, behaviorspace

I have a Netlogo model that sometimes causes an error at setup, because just by chance, there are not enough turtles within a set radius to select X of them. When I'm at the computer I just hit setup again and keep going.

When using behavior space, what will happen when it hits one of these errors please? It seems to ignore it and move on but still record the run in the output.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation suggests that the experiment will be interrupted:
http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html

But in any case, good programming practice in any case will prevent such possible runtime errors.  E.g., to try and get 2 partners in-radius 1 for each turtle:

```
to-report select-partners ;turtle proc
  let candidates (other turtles in-radius 1)
  if (2 < count candidates) [
    set candidates (n-of 2 candidates)
  ]
  report candidates ;may be an empty agentset!
end
```

Comment: iirc, that bit in the doc is no longer accurate — at one time a runtime error would abort the experiment, but people complained and we changed it, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I like Alan's answer.  But also, if you just want the failed setup to be retried, you might consider changing your setup commands from:

```
setup
```

to something more like

```
let done? false
while [not done?] [
  carefully [
    setup
    set done? true
  ] [ ]
]
```